# Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout when cloning private repo

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

I have got a Libraries project which I am pulling in my main project via composer like this:

```
 "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "package",
          "package": {
            "name": "testsystems/libraries-project",
            "version": "master",
            "source": {
              "url": "git@bitbucket.org:testsystems/libraries-project.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "master"
            },
            "autoload": {
              "psr-4": {
                "Test\\": "src/Test/"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

And then on require:

```
"testsystems/libraries-project": "master"
```

The issue is that `composer update` fails when it comes to installing this project with the following message:

```
 Cloning into '/var/www/test/vendor/test/libraries'...
  repository access denied.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

And then on `~/.ssh/config` I have added:

```
Host bitbucket.org
HostName altssh.bitbucket.org
Port 443
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `repository access denied` - Is it a private repository?

Comment: Yes, @MagnusEriksson. Both repos are part of the same Project of the same Team in Bitbucket.

Comment: The bitbucket repo URL in your "source" looks strange. Shouldn't it be: `git@bitbucket.org:testsystems/libraries-project.git`?

Comment: Updated- sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The git-url in your composer file is still invalid. You need to have the tld `.org` or Composer has no chance in finding that file.

Comment: You keep updating the question after reading the comments. Are you actually trying these changes without success? Is the above an actual copy/paste (which it should be) of your real code or is a re-write for SO (which is useless since you can, and have, introduced even more issues that way)? Just silently updating the code in the question doesn't tell us _anything_.

Comment: I am still getting the same message unfortunately.
Changes are actually a rewrite because I can't obviously disclose the real code. 
So, any suggestions by the way?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question: using HTTPS instead Git worked fine in my case.

`https://thitami@bitbucket.org/testrepo/libraries-project.git`